# Scaling HiDpi Full HD screen on Ubuntu Gnome (and multi monitors)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a 14" Full HD display screen. It's probably not qualified to be called a hidpi/retina, but it still is very dense. The problem is that the minimum 2x scaling in Tweak Tools is too much. Ideally I wish I could set this to 1.2-1.3.

Scaling the fonts as someone suggests in these cases, from time to time, is not a viable answer since the interfaces will still be small. It produces a very quirky and ugly UI.

Finally, I sometimes use this laptop with external displays. Those can be as well beyond HD but still, the ratio wouldn't be the same as this laptop. Additionally to the issues above, is there a way to achieve what I want, per monitor basis? I think on Ubuntu/Unity (non-Gnome) you can set the font scaling at least on each monitor separately. Not sure on Gnome.

I think this could be achieved by Xrandr, but would be changes persistent? Has anyone written a GUI tool for that?

Thanks

Comment: This  might interest you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958261/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the experimental feature 'fractional scaling' of gnome 3.26 (which is part of ubuntu 17.10) and set it to 125%.

You can set the scaling of each monitor separately. To use this feature you have to use Wayland instead of xorg

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux

Comment: Thanks, too bad it only works with Wayland. I've found Wayland very unstable (actually unusable) in my 3 monitors setup. So I can't even try that. Has multi monitor support improved in 17.10? I'm in 17.04, but even in past versions Wayland never worked for me with multi monitors.