# Fractional scaling Gnome 3.26/Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome

I'm really looking forward to 17.10 with Gnome and other new features. One key feature from previous versions of Ubuntu is fractional scaling where I found a value of 1.25 to be perfect (14", 2680x1440).

Gnome 3.26 is supposed to support fractional scaling but I haven't found this in the settings of the 17.10 beta. I can only choose between 100% (too small for me) and 200% (way too big...).

Will Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome 3.26 support fractional scaling?

Best regards,

Håkan

Answer (score 6):

According to one recent [OMG! Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux)

> Despite the best efforts of many fractional scaling wasn’t ready for the GNOME 3.26 release earlier this month.

As it is [now finalised](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2017-August/001221.html) that Ubuntu 17.10 is going to have [GNOME shell v3.26](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/gnome-shell) most probably fractional scaling won't be included in Ubuntu 17.10.

But the same article provides a workaround to enable experimental fractional scaling in GNOME 3.26, although it works only in the *Wayland session*. Apparently it can be activated by running the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

Then you should see a number of extra scaling options in the **Scale** section of *Settings > Devices > Displays*.
[image]
(Screenshot from the same article)

Comment: But how to obtain per display fractional scaling? Where to set DPI for monitor 1 to eg. 150% and monitor 2 to 125%  ?

Comment: What is a "Wayland session?"

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol) Wayland replaced Xorg as the default session in Ubuntu 17.10 (but you can still switch to Xorg if you wish)

Comment: @pomsky Ah, I just upgraded and I think my default session is Xorg. How do I switch to Wayland?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10 If Wayland is not available, then most probably it's disabled by your hardware (Nvidia is not working nicely).

Comment: @pomsky Interesting. I'm not using nvidia but the only options I saw were Xorg on Ubuntu and Unity. Hm ...