# Fractional scaling in Ubuntu 17.10 gives blurry font

Tags: gnome, fonts, display-resolution

As noted in several posts, the display scaling in Ubuntu 17.10 can only be set to 100, 200 or 300%.

For fractional scaling such as 125, 150%, the work around proposed
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958261/fractional-scaling-gnome-3-26-ubuntu-17-10) works but leave blurry font in applications. It there a way to restore sharp font and still maintain the fractional scaling?

Comment: Currently KDE/Plasma supports fractional scaling.  Probably not what you want to hear, but it is an option.  Also Gnome applications look nice on Plasma because you can theme them from inside Plasma Settings by default.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Would be nice if Gnome included the same feature

Comment: I think they are working on it..

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem as explained in that post. Although "dirty" is not the term I would use to qualify a font :)