# How do I scale menu and title bars in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, display

In old version of Ubuntu, we could set scale for menu and title bars:
[image: we could set scale for menu and title bars]

The "Scale for menu and title bars" is available.
But in Ubuntu 17.10 I don't see it in Settings>Devices>Displays.
[image: This is the image of the Settigs>Devces>Displays]

I understand that Ubuntu has switched from Unity to GNOME.
So how do I scale display in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: A similar question was asked here and answered - but was closed for now following guidelines.  But it is helpful. https://askubuntu.com/questions/958261/fractional-scaling-gnome-3-26-ubuntu-17-10

Answer (score 1):

This [OMG Ubuntu article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux) refers to this as "fractional scaling" and notes it has been excluded from the Gnome shell v3.26 used in Ubuntu 17.10.  However, it can be enabled "experimentally" by using the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

This will allow you to open 'Displays' (*Settings > Devices > Displays*) and see 'Scale' values other than 100% and 200%.

Your other option is to add the Untiy desktop back to Ubuntu 17.10 which retains the old scale factor options.